# Return element for a given XPATH also Next sibling element in java

Tags: java, jsoup

I need to Parse HTML in java. I'm looking for a package in java which return an element for a given XPATH (Like "div:nth-child(8) > a:nth-child(2)") also must have function to return next similar sibling element. I started with JSOUP which has a function to return next sibling element. But unfortunately it does not have a function to return an element for a given XPATH like "div:nth-child(8) > a:nth-child(2)" because it has its own Xpath notation.

Comment: In case my answer did solve your problem please consider accepting it. If you still have trouble with XPath, please tell us where the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

You can use different libraries for XPath:

1. The [built in XPath processor of Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html). It is part of Java since at least version 5, if i remember correctly.
2. [jaxen](http://jaxen.codehaus.org/)
3. [PsychoPathXPathProcessor](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PsychoPathXPathProcessor)
4. [Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/welcome/welcome.xml)

I am not sure what you mean by `must have function to return next similar sibling element`. I hope you find such functions in one of the mentioned libraries.